# Use of sbrk system call in Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, kernighan-and-ritchie

What is the use of `sbrk` system call in Unix and how is it to be used in C? Most of them say that `malloc` uses the `sbrk` system call to allocate memory. So, how does the `sbrk` system call allocate memory?  What are the arguments and return type of sbrk?

Comment: You can find a discussion of it in Kernighan & Ritchie, right at the end of the book proper.  Well, that last section is an implementation of `malloc()` and `free()` using `sbrk()` to get memory from the system.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html. tl;dr: "Avoid using brk() and sbrk()"

Answer (score 2):

`sbrk()` takes a positive integer as an argument. It increases the size of the current process's heap by that number of bytes, then returns a `void *` to the new end of the heap.

However, **the information you're reading is outdated**. To quote the Mac OS X manual page for this system call:

> The `brk` and `sbrk` functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management.

Modern systems do not use `sbrk()` for memory management, as it is incredibly limited. In particular, it cannot manage a heap which is not contiguous in memory! Instead, they use the `mmap()` system call to map new ranges of memory as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Function definition: `void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);`

> sbrk() increments the program's data space by `increment` bytes. Calling sbrk() with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current location of the program break.

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk